# Install a Maven library in a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, maven, dockerfile, mysql-connector, dockerfile-maven-plugin

I'm trying to build a docker image that installs this two maven libraries:

```
mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.29
com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:0.14.0
```

It has no problem with the build but this is what happen when I run it:

```
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException
```

And this is the code of my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM maven:latest

WORKDIR /app/
COPY . .
RUN mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:get \
    -DrepoUrl=https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.crealytics/spark-excel_2.12/0.14.0 \
    -Dartifact=com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:0.14.0 && \
    mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:get \
    -DrepoUrl=https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java \
    -Dartifact=mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.29
```

Comment: Dear @lourdes, Welcome to Stack Overflow! How are you trying to build a Docker image? I have built the Docker image successfully by running the `docker build -t maven-get-example .` command.

Comment: Hello @Brunov, thank you! Yes, I could built the image too. The problem is that I can not run it, I used docker run image-example

Comment: Dear @lourdes, What is your goal? Are you trying to build a Maven project inside a Docker container? Could you please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that one can build and run it to reproduce the problem?